# Raspberry Zero USB connection Lost and don't detected again in Linux OS As USB Devices

Tags: usb, lcd

I was installing my [LCD 5 Inch TFT](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi50vzo683iAhVBKewKHbFxAUwQjhx6BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FElecrow-Capacitive-interface-Supports-Raspberry%2Fdp%2FB07FDYXPT7&psig=AOvVaw36ctaB3I3i8u5jjNgH3lXr&ust=1559669502098706) files in my raspberry Zero which connected to my PC (Linux LMDE), and after a while i have a mistake pressed accidentally some keyboard bottoms and then  with this results I have lost my connection to Pi zero via terminal and now my Pi don't recognized by USB port.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ls
LCD-show  LCD-show.tar.gz
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ cd LCD-show
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/LCD-show $ sudo ./LCD5-show
this is raspberrypi kernel
1200
need to update touch configuration
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-input-evdev.
(Reading database ... 80889 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.3-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-input-evdev (1:2.10.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-evdev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
^[[B0Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
reboot
0000000000packet_write_wait: Connection to 192.168.7.2 port 22: Broken pipe
so@notebook:~$ sudo ssh pi@192.168.7.2  
^Z
[9]+  Stopped                 sudo ssh pi@192.168.7.2
so@notebook:~$ sudo ssh pi@192.168.7.2
ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22: Connection timed out
```

[image]
I have another Pi zero which is new and by inserting my the previous SD card to new Pi zero this new Pi also don't recognized by my PC.

I s this problem because of my Linux OS, And if I use Window 8 OS this problem don't occurred?

**Update**:

I have done the routine to install the [LCD 5 Inch driver](https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git) vi new SD Rasberian OS and without any mistake in installing i have inserted this commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git
chmod -R 755 LCD-show
cd LCD-show/
sudo ./LCD5-show
```

And i get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/LCD-show $ sudo ./LCD5-show
this is raspberrypi kernel
1200
need to update touch configuration
Selecting previously unselected package xserver-xorg-input-evdev.
(Reading database ... 80889 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.3-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-input-evdev (1:2.10.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-evdev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
reboot
Connection to 192.168.7.2 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.7.2 closed.
```

and After this i could not connect to my Pi Zero Again!!!!

the boot folder of SD card hase been changed and the **config.txt** file changed to this:

```
# For more options and information see
# http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=on
enable_uart=1
# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapxy=0,pmax=255,xohms=150,xmin=200,xmax=3900,ymin=200,ymax=3900
```

And the **cmdline.txt** file changed to this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fbcon=map:10 fbcon=font:ProFont6x11 logo.nologo
```

As you can see the `dtoverlay=dwc2` text in **config.txt** file has been removed, and `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` text in the **cmdline.txt** file too removed.Also the ssh file in boot folder too removed.

I have changed those files above described abased of [this instruction](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/) and it's again working and detecting but i guess i must do this camand to install LCD 5 Inch driver in Raspberry Zero Via USB OTG connection:

```
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install  xserver-xorg-input-evdev
```

but again i get this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop/LCD-show $ sudo ./LCD5-show
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d’: File exists
this is raspberrypi kernel
1200
need to update touch configuration
dpkg: warning: downgrading xserver-xorg-input-evdev from 1:2.10.5-1 to 1:2.10.3-1
(Reading database ... 80962 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack xserver-xorg-input-evdev_1%3a2.10.3-1_armhf.deb ...
Unpacking xserver-xorg-input-evdev (1:2.10.3-1) over (1:2.10.5-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-input-evdev:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev depends on xorg-input-abi-22; however:
  Package xorg-input-abi-22 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-input-evdev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
reboot
Connection to 192.168.7.2 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.7.2 closed.
```

Comment: My be this question is related : [https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=242427&p=1478680#p1478680](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=242427&p=1478680#p1478680) and [https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=242274&p=1478682#p1478682](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=242274&p=1478682#p1478682) the LCDshow driver files needs to be hacked because of unusual USB connection. 

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.